# Click once and remove all element not one by one javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi the code below shows overlay when you click the welcomediv id for my menu. when the overlay shows up and you click the element itself it will remove first the div inside him what im trying to do is to remove all of them with the element inside the overlay once you click them also when you click outside the overlay

```
 init=()=>{
        //SELECT & BIND (CLICK) EVENT
        document.querySelector('a.menuToggle, a#welcomeDivs').addEventListener('click',modal.overlay.init);
    }
    modal={
        overlay:{
            init:()=>{
                //CREATE OVERLAY 
                var overlay = document.createElement('overlay');
                overlay.id = 'welcomeDivsss';
                //SET (CLICK) EVENT TO REMOVE ITSLEF
                overlay.addEventListener('click',modal.overlay.remove);

                //APPEND TO INTERFACE
                document.body.appendChild(overlay);

                // After overlay added to html. "welcomeDivsss" is overlay id you specified.
                $( "#welcomeDivsss" ).append( '<div class="parela" id="welcomeDiv" <div class="inner_box"> <a onclick="click" class="closes"></a> </div> </div>' );

            },
            remove:(e)=>{
                //REMOVE ITSELF
                e.target.parentNode.removeChild(e.target);
            }       
        }
    }

    //ON DOCUMENT LOAD RUN INIT
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',init);
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand. What do you mean you want to remove "all of them" ? What is "them" ?

Answer (score 0):

What about you change your remove function?

If I understood your problem, that code will resolve the issue:

```
        ...
        remove:()=>{
            // you can remove by the id, because it's unique
            document.getElementById('welcomeDivsss').remove();
        }
        ...
```